# spoon - merge two CSV using an ID

Tags: csv, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have two CSV,
the first is like:

```
ID, name, surname
ABC//001, John, Doe
```

the second is like:

```
ID, mail, phone
001, john@doe.com, 001 001001
```

The problem is the ID, in the first file there is a string before the actual ID.

I tried with merge Join but (I think) this step require that the columns must be equals.

I use Kettle - Spoon Stable Release - 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2nd file input step, choose the type as String for column ID. It's working for me that way.